# Parsing json text inside a script tag using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, findall

I'm trying to extract the text in the `@context` element of (`'script', type='application/ld+json'`) in Python3 by using BeautifulSoup.

I have multiple scripts inside one page and I would to like to get specific features listed in the json above.

I tried to use this code :

```
data = soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')
print(data)
```

This gave me the completed extract content of all the scripts but I would like to get a specific feature inside the context of each scripts.

Example of feature:

```
{"name":"test","telephone":"600.212.0000","url":"https://test.com/test"}
```

For this example I would like to get the `"url"` part.

Does anybody know to do it in Python?

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Since your feature is a dict you can try the following:

```
feature = {"name":"test","telephone":"600.212.0000","url":"https://test.com/test"}
print(feature["url"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension with `get()`:

```
data = soup.find_all('script', type='application/ld+json')

urls = [i.get('url') for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's missing from other answers is converting the contents extracted from the script tag into a JSON (for which we can use the json library) and then just select the field we're interested in from the dict.

```
import requests, json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

src = requests.get("YOUR_URL").content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'html.parser')
res = soup.find('script', type='application/ld+json')

json_object = json.loads(res.contents[0])
print(json_object['url'])
```